# Map Oracle timestamp type to java.sql.Timestamp or java.util.Date using Hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have an existing database with hundreds of tables using `TIMESTAMP(6)` as the data type for some columns.

When I reverse engineered this database using Hibernate, the Java type `Serializable` is used to map these columns.

How can I get Hibernate to automatically map columns in these hundreds of tables to `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.util.Date`?

This question is related to [How to map oracle timestamp to appropriate java type in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473866/how-to-map-oracle-timestamp-to-appropriate-java-type-in-hibernate/2478274#2478274)  However, the answer to that question was a work around involving an ant task modifying the generated classes.  I don't want to modify the generated classes, I want to get the right type in the first place.

I see there's a solution like

```
<sql-type jdbc-type="OTHER" hibernate-type="java.sql.Timestamp" />
```

I wouldn't mind if the solution was more like

```
<sql-type jdbc-type="TIMESTAMP" hibernate-type="java.sql.Timestamp" />
```

But I don't want all unmapped types (`OTHER`) to go to `java.sql.Timestamp`.  I would like to simply tell Hibernate to map these Oracle timestamps to Java's timestamp class.

When I use Netbeans to do the mapping, it detects the timestamp in Oracle and properly converts it.  I cannot use Netbeans though because I would like to use an automated tool in my build script so I'm using Hibernate.

Comment: What's relationship between Netbeans and Hibernate?

Comment: There is no relationship between Netbeans and Hibernate.  I was just making the point that Netbeans can do the mapping, so I know it can be done.  Hibernate may not be able to do the mapping because it may have a limitation that Netbeans doesn't have.  Perhaps I should use the same tool that Netbeans uses... but I don't know if it can be used from within my build script.