# Mapping Oracle types TimestampWithTimezone and TimestampWithLocalTimeZone to Hibernate types in reverse engineering

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-tools

I have a table with three columns with sql type as TimeStamp,TimeStampWithTimeZone and TimeStampWithLocalTimeZone.

In the hibernate reverse engineer process,

> **TimeStamp** is correctly mapped to **Timestamp**.
>
> But **TimeStampWithTimeZone** and **TimeStampWithTimeZone**  is mapped to **Seralizable**, expecting both should map to **TimeStamp**.

After going though this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473866/how-to-map-oracle-timestamp-to-appropriate-java-type-in-hibernate),I have add below mapping in hibernate.reveng.xml.

```
<sql-type jdbc-type="OTHER" hibernate-type="java.sql.Timestamp" />
```

But still I they are mapping it to Seralizable.Do any one faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by extending default RevengNamingStrategy.

**Approach :**
Sql Types of TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE and TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIMEZONE types are -101 and -102 and as there is no hibernate mapping types in **java.sql.Types** for these types,hence they are mapping to seralizable.

So Wrote my own RevengNamingStrategy,which converts these type to Timestamp.Which intern converts to hibernate TimeStampType.

```
public class OracleRevengNamingStrategy extends DefaultRevengNamingStrategy {

    private static final Integer TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE_SQL_CODE = -101;

    private static final Integer TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIMEZONE_SQL_CODE = -102;


    public OracleRevengNamingStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    // Converts Timestamp with tomezone and Time stamp with local time zone to Timestamp
    @Override
    public String columnToHibernateTypeName(TableIdentifier table, String columnName, int sqlType, int length, int precision, int scale,
                                            boolean nullable, boolean generatedIdentifier) {
        String type;

        if (sqlType == TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE_SQL_CODE || sqlType == TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIMEZONE_SQL_CODE) {
            type = "timestamp";
        } else {
            type = super.columnToHibernateTypeName(table, columnName, sqlType, length, precision, scale, nullable, generatedIdentifier);
        }

        return type;
    }

}
```

Please let me know if any other approaches to handle this issue.