# how to store date AND time with JPA in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, date, jpa

I'm using WebSphere 7 (Java EE 5) and OpenJPA 1.2.1.

I have a JPA object with a "`modifiedTimestamp`" attribute, something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Widget {
  /* ... */
  private java.sql.Date modifiedTimestamp;
  /* ... */
}
```

The related field in the Oracle database is of type `DATE`.

I set the date like so ...

```
myWidget.setModifiedTimestamp(new java.sql.Data(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

... and it gets stored, but when I read it back the time of day hasn't been stored, it allows comes back as 24:00.

Is this a JPA thing, or an Oracle thing?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Good question -- I'm using WebSphere 7 (Java EE 5) and OpenJPA 1.2.1.

Comment: java.sql.Date stores date only, as per its javadocs. Perhaps you want java.util.Date?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188768/java-type-for-date-time-when-using-oracle-date-with-hibernate for hibernate, i guess you may try that

Comment: When I change the code to `private java.util.Date modifiedTimestamp` the automatic mapping seems to break, I get this error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/myapp/domain/Widget.getModifiedTimestamp()Ljava/sql/Data`

Comment: you have to recompile Widget.java ; clean it when in doubt.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to java.util.Date throughout, but I also needed to add the @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) annotation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Anotating your field and changing the type should help:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date modifiedTimestamp;
```

Comment: Note: To make it work I also changed the Oracle field to a TIMESTAMP instead of DATE.

Comment: In my case (Oracle 11g) the DATE datatype in Oracle is working, too.

Comment: Don't think so Calendar is already quite old and I never saw it used with JPA. The "new" date time api is in java.time but I never used it with JPA because I haven't been working with java in recent years. I actually tended to use JodaTime as much as possible as it had a much saner API on which java.time is based.

Answer (score 13):

Use `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` ([Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html)). Combined [with java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE_FIELD")
private java.util.Date modifiedTimestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyAccioly, I'd like to mark it correct by Eelke beat your by a matter of seconds. :)

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyAccioly, the Column annotation was missing in my case and fixed with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question has been asked a while ago so I'd suggest giving [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-java-time#after-java-8) article a read. There are some changes after java 8 date types were introduced. I know it's not an answer to this question and the problem I had was different but I'm posting this because the `@Temporal()` annotation I saw in the answer was breaking my CI pipeline:

This works:

```java
@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIME") // this bit is different
@JsonFormat(pattern="HH:mm")
private LocalTime startTime;
```

This doesn't:

```java
@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@JsonFormat(pattern="HH:mm")
private LocalTime startTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the type to `java.sql.Timestamp` then also it should work, without adding `@Temporal` annotaion.

```
private java.sql.Timestamp modifiedTimestamp;
```

Of course in Oracle change field to a TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle datetime field in Java, MySQL db and OpenJPA2. I want field to be a type of java.util.Calendar, dbfield datetime and dbvalue as UTC value. Mysql knows nothing about timezone so using a custom converter can set and read "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" string. Still its valid datetime sql column and java.util.Calendar in entity bean.

```
@Entity @Table(name="user") @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;    // primary key (autogen surrogate)

    private String name;

    @Column(name="updated_utc") // use custom serializer so that UTC-stringified
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) // db datetime is properly set to calendar instance
    @Factory("JPAUtil.db2calendar") @Externalizer("JPAUtil.calendar2db")
    private Calendar updated;

    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name=name; }

    public Calendar getUpdated() { return updated; }
    public void setUpdated(Calendar cal) { updated=cal; }

}

- - - 

public class JPAUtil {
    public static final TimeZone TIMEZONE_UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

    public static String calendar2db(Calendar val, StoreContext ctx) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TIMEZONE_UTC);
        return df.format(cal.getTime()); // return date as UTC string value
    }

    public static Calendar db2calendar(String val, StoreContext ctx) {
        try {
            // returned calendar is using a default timezone, val was set as utc string
            return DateUtil.parseDateTimeFromUTC(val);
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
            return null;
        }
    }

}

- - - 

CREATE TABLE user (
  id bigint NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  updated_utc datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY USERNAME (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

ps: DateUtil is my random util class to provide some basic conversions.