# How to use JPA to save datetime of SQL to fix: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

I got a very frustrated problem.. I cannot use the JPA save function to store correct datetime object of SQL, I got the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

There is my code:

In Controller:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@PostMapping("/record")
public String updateRecord(@RequestParam("createDatetime") Timestamp createDatetime) { 
        
Date date = new Date();
        Timestamp ts=new Timestamp(date.getTime());

        Record record = new Record();
        Record.setCreateDatetime(ts);

        recordService.save(record);
}
```

In Entity:

```
private Timestamp createDatetime;

@Column(name = "createDatetime")
public Timestamp getCreateDatetime() {
        return createDatetime;
}

public void setCreateDatetime(Timestamp createDatetime) {
        this.createDatetime= createDatetime;
}
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: (1) Show your table schema. (2) Prefer `Instant` to `Timestamp`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I think `Instant` is not supported out-of-the-box by JPA.

Comment: @Turing85 It's supported by Hibernate, which is the default if someone isn't familiar enough with JPA to have tagged another provider.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The Data Type in SQL DB is datetime.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15658215/185565 for JPA custom datetime with Calendar2String type but you may use any type case you want such as Calendar2Date etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to use `LocalDateTime` of modern `java.time`. JPA automatically convert `LocalDateTime` into database `datetime`. To get current datetime use `LocalDateTime.now()`.

```
private LocalDateTime createDatetime;

@Column(name = "createDatetime")
public LocalDateTime getCreateDatetime() {
        return createDatetime;
}
```

You can take as `@RequestParam` also

```
@PostMapping("/record")
public String updateRecord(@RequestParam("createDatetime") LocalDateTime createDatetime) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotate createDateTime field with @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however it does not work using @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP); I'm using Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.3, does it support?